# Are there universal Chinese system fonts?

Tags: types, fonts, system, typography

I am working with a Chinese brand company and would like to remove some of their image links and replace them with fonts. I am having a hard time finding a authoritative source regarding the availability of Chinese fonts.

Does anyone know any fonts that are pushed on both OSx and Windows systems? I have seen quality English font comparisons, but would like to find something Chinese related. If I don't get any promising answers, I may have to make it myself...

Comment: Been a while, yes, but were you able to answer your question?

Comment: If you want to use the popular "[system font stack](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/system-font-stack/)" but include a nicer font for Chinese, add the `Microsoft YaHei` font to the stack, source: https://gao.md/blog/2018/05/13/modern-css-font-stack-for-chinese-website/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is a list of fonts http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CJK_fonts

I can tell you that the most popular chinese font is simsun and that the vast majority of users are on windows and i mean an extremely high number. Even people who buy mac books will install windows on them. I think you should look through the wiki list and choose the one you think is best. FYI the reason they used the images is to solve the exact problem you are not facing

Comment: I had found this earlier. Its a great resource for general stuff. Im looking for something like http://www.webspaceworks.com/resources/fonts-web-typography/48/
I noticed that big sites like Wikipedia, Apple, Google in China don't declare their fonts. Its almost always Arial. I'm wonder if declaring a Chinese font will result in errors. Specifically a san-serif font. Apple declares Lucidia, Google declares Arial, Wikipedia declares san-serif, but are they all loading a common across systems?